# QlistView update when updating a list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QModel and QListview, shows items from a global variable(list). This list is being updated by adding items to it. I have two questions:

1. How to make listview with two Columns and set headers from two list (e.g. ['name', 'quantity'])?
2. How to install a signal, and emit a signal on list update to update the Qlistview and QModel? and update Bothe columns
   I wanted to try `installEvent`, and `@setter` to the list, but didn't know how to go.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


Mylist   = ['Apple','Orange','lemon']
Quantity = ['5','2','7']


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mylist, mylist2):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # mylist
        self.mylist = mylist
        self.mylist2 = mylist2

        # layout
        Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Model and listview
        self.viewL = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        """Q1: How to make QStandardItemModel with a second column with header
           e.g. headres['name', 'Quantity']
        """

        # Add items
        for Name in self.mylist:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(Name)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.model.appendRow(item)
         """ How to add from 2nd list to 2nd column
         """

        # set the model
        self.viewL.setModel(self.model)

        # 
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Item')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        #
        Layout.addWidget(self.viewL)
        Layout.addWidget(button)
        self.show()

    def onClick(self, index):
        self.mylist.append('mango')
        self.mylist2.append('10')
        """ How to emit a signal on on appending a list, then update the model and listview
        """


app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=Window(mylist=Mylist, mylist2=Quantity)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QListView supports a single column, so if you want multiple columns then use a QTableView, on the other hand it is not necessary to create a signal to add items, you just have to add the information to the model:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, first_column, second_column, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView(
            showGrid=False, selectionBehavior=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
        )
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name", "quantity"])
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

        for first_text, second_text in zip(first_column, second_column):
            item_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(first_text)
            item_1.setCheckable(True)
            item_1.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

            item_2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(second_text)

            self.model.appendRow([item_1, item_2])

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Item")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        # layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        #
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(button)

    def onClick(self):
        item_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("mango")
        item_1.setCheckable(True)
        item_1.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        item_2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("10")

        self.model.appendRow([item_1, item_2])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Mylist = ["Apple", "Orange", "lemon"]
    Quantity = ["5", "2", "7"]

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(Mylist, Quantity)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

``
```

Comment: Thanks. I hoped to get an answer on how to sent a signal when appending to the list, since in actual code, the list and ListView are separated. But, I think I can call onClick function after appending to a list.